# Query process dom inside a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML snippet which I'd like to get>modify>display, here is HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 loader" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100%; z-index: 99; right: 0px;  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);">
       <span class="text-center" style="padding-top: 20%; display: inherit;">
          <img id="IDloaderGif"  src="{{asset('imgs/gears.gif')}}" >
          <p style="font-size: 30px;">Loading ...</p>
       </span>
</div>
```

and here where I'm processing the snippet :

```
function (callback) {

                  $.ajax({
                    url: app.url('js/html/loader.html'),
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {},
                  }).done(function(data) {
                     var data = $(jQuery.parseHTML(data)).find('#IDloaderGif').attr('src', app.url('imgs/gears.gif'));
                        callback(data);
                  });

 }
```

so here is my problem:

`$(jQuery.parseHTML(data)).find('#IDloaderGif').attr('src', app.url('imgs/gears.gif'));`

this does find the element and modifies it, but `var data` now contains only this element, only the element with selected id : `'#IDloaderGif'` but I needed the entire snippet but it gives me only that element , not the whole snippet, so I need to modify the snippet without loosing the whole data.|thank you|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find()` returns only the found element, so set the entire HTML to the `data` variable, then find and modify

```
var data = $(jQuery.parseHTML(data));

data.find('#IDloaderGif').attr('src', app.url('imgs/gears.gif'));

callback(data);
```

Comment: fk, my little brain was close to this solution, it was somewhere in my subconscious :D , thank You.